# change background color in another blade using variable in laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm working with Laravel right now and can't figure out how I can apply different background colors on page that i want ..

Actually, I want to change the background of my page which I convert to PDF

**here is my route**

```
Route::get('/form/{slug}/pdf/{id}/{color?}', ['as' => 'generate.pdfColor', 'uses' => 'OriginController@changeColor']);
```

**here is my function of the controller**

```
public function changeColor(Request $request, $slug, $id = null, $myColor){  
    $colors=[
        1=> ['color'=>'#1e90ff'],
        2=> ['color'=>'#2ecc71'],
        3=> ['color'=>'#e84118'],
        4=> ['color'=>'#222D32'],
        5=> ['color'=>'#ffcccc'],
        6=> ['color'=>'#910000']
    ]; 
    return  view('layouts.modules.student_pdf',['data'=>$colors[$myColor]]); 
}
```

**here is my link to sending parameter of the color** 
in this example  1 is (`#1e90ff`)

```
<a  target="_blank" href='<?php echo e(route('generate.pdfColor', ['slug' => 'student', 'id' => '56', 'color' => '1'])); ?>'>
    <i class='fa fa-file-pdf-o 2x avatar'></i>
    &nbsp;change color
</a>
```

**and this my page `cv_pdf.blade.php` that i want to change the bg**

```
 <!-- left -->
    <div class="left" id="left_pdf" style="background:{{data['color']}}  ; " > 
     ..............
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: yes ..here is the error "Use of undefined constant data - assumed 'data' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)"

Answer (score 2):

You just missed the `$` sign for `$data` variable

```
//Fix
<div class="left" id="left_pdf" style="background:{{$data['color']}}  ; " >
```

Answer (score 0):

change `function changeColor` like below:

```
public function changeColor(Request $request, $slug, $id = null, $myColor){  
   //just change return line like below
   return  view('layouts.modules.student_pdf')->with(['color' => $colors[$myColor]['color']]); 
}
```

and in `page_cv_pdf.blade.php` do as follows:

```
<div class="left" id="left_pdf" style="background-color:{{$color}};" > 
      ..............
</div>
```

Comment: There is a error says "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: @HamzaDriouCh edit my answers, return this `  return  view('layouts.modules.student_pdf')->with(['color' => $colors[$myColor]['color']]); 
`